# Assigning Web Service response data to NSManagedObject subclass

Tags: ios, core-data, nsdictionary, nsmanagedobject, key-value

Currently I am doing one by one assignment to all the attributes of CoreData Entity, like following;

```
employee.first_name = [responseDict valueForKey:@"first_name"];
employee.last_name = [responseDict valueForKey:@"last_name"];
employee.middle_name = [responseDict valueForKey:@"middle_name"];

// And So On... for say, like 100+ more attributes.
```

Problem: There are many entities are about to be introduced & I want to avoid these manual assignment.

Question: Is there any smarter way to accomplish this?

Hope I am making myself clear. Let me know, if any information needed.

Comment: You should add a custom `initWithDictionary` method to the `Employee` class, but basically, no it will have to use the same logic.

Comment: Is your problem that there are many different entities (Employee, Department, etc), or many different attributes (firstName, middleName, etc), or many different objects (ie instances of the Employee class)?  Or a combination of the three?

Comment: Problem is that, I want to avoid these assignments for all the attributes. Like some logic which involves all the keys and values to be inserted with just one statement. Hope I am making sense, here.

Answer (score 2):

If you're **certain** that the incoming dictionary keys are **all** present on your managed object entity, you can do the assignment in one step using `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:`

```
[employee setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:responseDict];
```

But I mean it about being certain. This will call `setValue:forKey:` on `employee` for every key found in `responseDict`. If `responseDict` contains any keys that `employee` won't recognize, you'll get an exception saying that `employee` doesn't conform to key-value coding for the key.

If you're not certain, a safe approach would be to create an `NSManagedObject` subclass for `employee`, and have that subclass declare a list of property names it expects to receive from the web service. For example if an `Employee` class had an `NSArray` that looked like this:

```
self.webServicePropertyNames = @[ @"first_name", @"last_name", @"middle_name"];
```

...you could then iterate through that array and use `setValue:forKey` to assign every value, but use generic code.

Beyond that you can get into using the Objective-C run time to look up property names on `employee` and then find them in `responseDict`. This would end up working more or less like `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:` except without the danger of trying to assign nonexistent key values. This isn't trivial but [I wrote up a blog post describing the process a while ago](http://www.cimgf.com/2012/01/11/handling-incoming-json-redux/).

Comment: Reading your blog post. Seems promising solution. +1

Answer (score 2):

I once had a case like this: about 35 entities and many hundred attributes to be ported to a new web API. What I did was the following:

First I created mapping dictionaries (as plists) that matched the web API entity and attribute names to my Core Data ones. This is often necessary, as web APIs sometimes use names such as `"id"` or `"description"` which are reserved words in Core Data.

If there is no data type validation necessary you can now just use KVC to assign the attributes like this.

```
for (NSString *key in responseDictionary.allKeys) {
   NSString *entityKey = mappingDictionary[key];
   [entityInstance setValue:responseDictionary[key] forKey:entityKey];
}
```

If you want to compare data types it becomes a bit more complicated. Look at the `NSAttributeDescription` APIs that will help you. It inherits from `NSPropertyDescription` which includes the `name` property (equivalent to above `entityKey`). You can get all attributes from an `NSEntityDescription` with `attributesByName` or all properties (including relationships) by fast enumeration:

```
NSEntityDescription *anEntity = ...;
for (NSPropertyDescription *property in anEntity) {
    // property is each instance of NSPropertyDescription in anEntity in turn
}
```

Comment: I have data type validations there, Looking into `NSAttributeDescription` APIs. Thanks +1